# How can I fill a grid from MySQL and PHP? ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, extjs4

I know this question has been published before (a bunch of times actually) but I'm asking it because I have absolutely no idea what I can be doing wrong.

What I'm trying to do is just that, filling (or binding) a grid with data that I've got stored in my MySQL database.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Ext.define('UserDataModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'age']
});

var usersStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'UserDataModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'dbhandler/acquisition.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'usersData'
        }
    }
});

var gridPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: usersStore,
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'name',
        header: 'Name',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'age',
        header: 'Age',
        flex: 1
    }]
});
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
include('../connections/usersdb.php');

$query = "SELECT Name, Age FROM Users";
$result = $conn->query($query);

$usersData = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($usersData, array("name" => $row['Name'], "age" => $row['Age']))
    }
}

$conn->close();

echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "usersData" => $usersData)); ?>
```

But the grid isn't getting filled. 
And what drives even crazier is that the console doesn't throw me any error.

Comment: What does your server respond? Do you get the full json as expected?

Comment: How can I know that? Is there any proxy property calling a function where I can log the response into the console after it's done with the php file?

Comment: Omg, I just found the error. I didn't put a ';' at the end of array_push, I've been struggling with this the entire noon. I cannot believe it. :(

Comment: Time to start checking your error logs and/or enable error reporting

Comment: @RottenCheese you could simply check from the developer tool of your browser (eg chrom developer tool) or firebug extension. The network tab should show details of all AJAX requests